# Pasar datos de localstorage a php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, local-storage

Necesito pasar un dato de `localstorage` a una variable **php**, ya almaceno el dato en un **script** en la misma pagina pero me llega `null` a **php**, no se que estoy haciendo mal o que me falta, Adjunto mi código, gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

los datos los capturo de un formulario con un select, en un echo de php con la función guardar(), como dije me llega al localstorage e incluso la veo el valor en la función local() la funcion local se ejecuta al cargar la pagina y toma el dato del localstorage y lo envía a php mediante ajax (o eso se supone que haría), pero llega null a php.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function guardar () {
  var count = document.getElementById('count').value;
  localStorage.setItem('count', count);
  var con = localStorage.getItem('count');
  saved = parseInt(con);
  console.log('count');
  alert(saved);
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function local(){
 var con = localStorage.getItem('count');
 var  saved = parseInt(con);
 alert(saved);
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "index.php",         
           data:  {data: saved},
           success: function(data) {
              $('#output').html(data);
              alert(saved);
           }
        });
    };
</script>

<?php 
$saved = $_POST['data'];
?>
```

Comment: Lo mandas a la misma página o index.php es otra?

Comment: todo es en la misma pagina.

Comment: me puedes compartir como resolviste la el problema inicial que tenías, tengo el mismo problema Saludos!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder capturar el valor tienes que agregar el siguiente codigo :

```
<?php
    $resultado = array('mensaje' => '');
    if( isset($_POST['data']) ) {
        $resultado['mensaje'] = "Viene el valor : ".$_POST['data'];
        echo json_encode($resultado);
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Donde verificamos que venga el valor `$_POST['data]`, si viene, agregamos al arreglo `$resultado` el valor de mensaje (esto es solo un ejemplo).

Mientras que en tu funciones javascript las dejamos tal como estaban excepto, que al `ajax` le agregamos el parametro `dateType : 'json'`

```
function local() {
  var con = localStorage.getItem('count');
  var saved = parseInt(con);
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "index.php",
      data: { data: saved },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
          //$('#output').html(data);
          alert(data.mensaje);
      },
      error: function(error) {
          alert(error);
          console.log(error);
      }
  });
};
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero sigue sin funcionar, los alert que puse me  muestran el valor, pero en php me marca error: undefined index data...

Comment: ¿tendrá algo que ver la ruta?, hay muchos archivos y este esta dentro de una carpeta, pero esto todo el código está en la pagina index.php.

Comment: Nunca habia hecho un AJAX a la misma pagina en la que estaba, intentaste crear un archivo, por ejemplo ejemplo.php y ahi capturar los valores POST?

Comment: es que debe ser así, es para hacer una paginación, lo que pretendo es, que me guarde ese valor en el localstorage para que cada que recargue la pagina, lo capture y lo mande en el $limit de la consulta select * from tabla limit $limit, $pagina. y pueda cambiar ese valor  que es el numero de registros que me muestre por pagina.  y no tenga que ser un numero fijo.

Comment: voy a montar un ejemplo y te comendo

Comment: @BastianBurst editare, ya encontre la solucion

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59697/discussion-between-sioesi-and-bastianburst).

Comment: me llega así "\"30\"" cuando doy echo  jsonenconde($resultado); ¿como hago para que me llegue e numero "30"? así podría hacer lo demás y funcionaria.

Comment: Depende de como estes armando el json en tu php, deja el codigo aqui

Comment: $resultado = array();
    if( isset($_POST['data']) ) {
        $resultado = $_POST['data'];
        echo  json_encode($resultado);
        exit;
        $saved = json_encode($resultado);

Comment: otra cosa me llega sin el datatype

Comment: Debes hacer `$resultado = array('numero' = > 0);` y luego `$resultado['numero'] = $_POST['data']`

Comment: en el echo de php sale esto array(1) { ["numero"]=> int(0) } , en console.log de data sale esto {"numero":"\"10\""}, la forma en la que interpreta la informacion ambos es el lio, asi que al pasar el dato por ejemplo $porpagina = post, pues pasa es la cadena de caracteres y no el dato, igual gracias por la ayuda, al parecer si llega pero no fui capaz de asignarle el valor a la variable en php, seguiré buscando :(

Comment: Este último código es engañoso, pues realmente no es PHP quien imprime el valor de la variable, sino de nuevo javascript, aunque puede sernos útil en ocasiones. PHP no almacena realmente el valor, puesto que Javascript lo interpreta nuestro navegador (local), mientras que PHP se ejecutó en tiempo mucho antes en el servidor (internet).

Comment: @BastianBurst ven al chat!, no quiero dejarte sin la solucion

Answer (score 0):

antes de tu ajax tienes `;` , cuando deberia de estar una `,`

Con el `;` , estas cerrando la entrada al ajax.. Lamento dar una respuesta como 5 a#os tarde XD... pero mejor tarde que nunca(?)

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/336783)

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo

1. Agrega un input oculto al formulario y cuando cargues el formulario asigna el valor al input, al enviar el formulario a php el valor viajará en los parámetros.
2. Puedes agregarlo como parámetro en la URL al llamar el php y recibirlo con get en php

Hay más formas pero con estás creo que puedes intentar